# Rails: How to manipulate find(params[])

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters

I am trying to use Object.find(params[]) to only return objects with :stage_id = integer

Here is my controller code

```
def show
    @lesson = Lesson.find(params[:id])
    @stage1 = @lesson.units(params[:stage_id] == 1)
    @stage2 = @lesson.units(params[:stage_id] == 2)
```

Each lesson has many units, each unit has either a stage_id = 1 or stage_id = 2, I want @stage1 to become an array with units that only have a stage_id value of 1. The same goes for stage2.

How can I properly use params to return only units that have the indicated table values?

Comment: You seem to have no grasp of the Ruby language and/or Rails. You'd be better off buying a book on ruby/rails and reading it instead of asking questions like these here.

Comment: thats rather unfortunate since ive been through several books and learning with stackoverflow seems to work the best as I go through tutorials. Do you have any specific recommendations?

Comment: Any, really. The code cited in your question is nowhere near being valid. Stackoverflow isn't supposed to be a place to learn a language but rather increase existing knowledge of a language and/or resolve problems not readily solvable by RTFM or Google.

Comment: Check out [Rails for Zombies](http://railsforzombies.org/). While fx_ was a little harsh, he is probably right in that any Rails book would contain queries of the type you're asking about here. That said, still, welcome to SO.

Comment: thanks :), i might have missed them when going through it the first time, a lot of info to digest haha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def show
  @lesson = Lesson.find(params[:id])
  @stage1 = @lesson.units.first(:conditions => { :stage_id => 1 })
  @stage2 = @lesson.units.first(:conditions => { :stage_id => 2 })
end
```

Comment: `@lesson.units` returns an association proxy.  It works kind of like a mix of an array and a model class. So `first` tells it to return one object instead of an array of objects.

Answer (score 0):

Ref [find](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#M001788)

```
@stage1 = Unit.find(:all, :conditions => ["stage_id=? AND lession_id=?" 1, params[:id]])


@stage2 = Unit.find(:all, :conditions => ["stage_id=? AND lession_id=?" 2, params[:id]])
```

Comment: thank you for this, what is the reason why you decided not to use @lesson?

Answer (score 0):

If Units are "always' going to be structured with Stages, one thing you could do to DRY up your code is to have a Stage model.  That allows flexibility to add more stages in the future without breaking code.  Assuming that relationship is properly established and data is good, you could do something like the following.

controller code

```
@lesson = Lesson.find(params[:id])
```

view code (haml)

```
- for stage in @lesson.stages
  = stage.name
  - for unit in stage.units
    = unit.name
```

Comment: thank you for the suggestion. I plan on using the units in a variety of ways beyond just stages. Stages are the starting point. Eventually I will use the units within other lessons. Its hard to fully know how I plan to use them as I build the web app. that seems to be the hardest thing to grasp since it is always changing.